# Does every sequence of deformation of singularities eventually become equisingular?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, singularity-theory

Suppose we are over a field of characteristic zero and $f_i\colon X_i\to \mathrm{Spec}(R_i)$ $(i=1,2,\cdots)$ are flat families of singularities over DVRs. Assume that the generic fiber of $f_i$ is isomorphic to the special fiber of $f_{i+1}$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ (so intuitively we have an infinite sequence of deformation of singularities). My questions is: does $f_i$ become equisingular for large enough $i$? Here we call a family $X\to S$ equisingular if we can find a resolution of singularities $Y\to X$ such that the induced map $(Y,E)\to S$ is smooth on every stratum of $E=$ the union of all exceptional divisors of the desingularisation.

Comment: Maybe versal deformation spaces help? A plausible (to me) statement that would imply this is that the dimension of the versal deformation space of the generic fiber is at most the dimension of the versal deformation space of the special fiber, with equality if and only if the family is equisingular.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! At least this may help when the singularities are isolated. For non-isolated singularities I'm not sure since the deformation space can have an infinite dimension (e.g. $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ may deform to $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^m=0$ for any integer $m$).

Comment: Yes, I was certainly imagining an isolated singularity. Maybe for a higher-dimensional singularity one can do an induction on the dimension - e.g. if the singularities are $n$-dimensional then the singularity at any $n$-dimensional generic point is isolated so if we handle the isolated case then those can only deform finitely many times, so all but finitely many of the deformations must fix these generic points. But I don't know if there's a theory of deformations fixing the generic point...